# How does the decimal type retain precision?

Tags: types, decimal

I'm not quite clear on how the decimal representation works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format

Let's take an example of a float that can't be represented finitely like 0.1

How does the decimal type ensure that 0.1 is represented in a finite representation? In other words how is precision ensured?

Comment: Which decimal type, exactly? Are you referring to the .NET [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) type? We can't read your mind.

Comment: Not just .NET decimal type. I'm asking about the generic decmal type.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type

Comment: The *generic decimal type* (i.e. one unconnected with any particular language) is not something that is *implemented*, therefore there can be no saying about how it *works*. What does work is specific implementations of the type in *various* languages. Unless you specify what language you have in mind, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal type is explained thoroughly [at this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)